# How to get nearby location on google maps give a lat and lng coordinates

Tags: geolocation

I wish to know how to get nearby location over a certain range of radius. 
For example I have location of stores data stored in the database, and I want to search for a coffee over a range of 25 radius or 40 radius or even more, from a given lat and lng coordinate and then display them with their various distance from this lat and lng coordinate. I saw an example on Google but it's not working.

Comment: Assuming you're going to do it with GoogleMaps, bear in mind that a single request never returns more than 10 results

Answer (score 0):

I would do the requested app as follows , i realize there are other ways to do it, i try:
would first go to Google code playground and get sample for the geo location.

rewrite the java script function so that it takes the longitude and latitude as parameters.

include the html file in your project , then create a webbrowser control in your csharp app.
then call the navigate to local page which will launch the page with the given longitude and latitude

Answer (score 0):

You may use iFreeTools Creator - an online database app builder over Google App Engine - to store and search the geo-location database.

For a step-by-step guide on how you can do this, refer to the following blog post..

[Building a Store Locator type Google Maps app over GAE, using iFreeTools](http://blogs.ifreetools.com/2010/11/building-store-locator-type-google-maps.html)

// Disclosure : I wrote code for this web-app.